# Javascript reduce, count from second occurence

Tags: javascript, count, reduce

I have a simple array named adct with just one member 'title', and I am grouping/counting with reduce function. The code below works as intended, but I actually want to count elements from second occurrence only, not the first. I assume that is simple, but I cannot figure out how to do it. Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
    let result = adct.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.title] = r[a.title] || [];
        r[a.title]++;
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*from second occurrence*"? What are example inputs and what are the expected outputs for your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant method but here's what I came up with

```
let result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries( // wrap the reduce as an array
    adct.reduce(function(r, a) {
      r[a.title] = r[a.title] || [];
      r[a.title]++;
      return r; }, Object.create(null)))
    .filter(e=>e[1]>0)) // filter out the zeroes
```

```js
const adct=[{title:'fred'}, {title:'fred'}, {title:'fred'}, {title:'wilma'}, {title:'wilma'}, {title:'fred'}];

let result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(adct.reduce(function(r, a) {
  r[a.title] = r[a.title] || [];
  r[a.title]++;
  return r;
}, Object.create(null)))
.map(e=>{ e[1]--; return e;})
.filter(e=>e[1]>0))

console.log(result)

/* result:
{
  "fred": 3,
  "wilma": 1
}
*/
```

Comment: It is elegant enough for me, and it works great. Thank you very much!

Comment: I updated my answer so now your `for...in` loop will work the way you want

Comment: It does. Thanks again.